# navigating to a page class in a library in WP8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, uri

I have created a page class in the windows phone class library and I referenced that dll in windows phone app project(WP8).

Now how do i navigate to the page class created in the library..**How do i specify the uri?**
The exact API and syntax would help please.

I have tried using the **this.frame.Navigate(typeof(pagename))** as well as the **NavigationService.Navigate(new uri("/pagename.xaml",UriKind.relative))**..Both of the above are not working..I am assuming there is a mistake in the path specified in the uri..

Comment: What is the error you are getting when using `this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(pagename));` ?

Because I just tried it myself (in a windows phone class library) and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following did work for me correctly.

```
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AssemblyName;component/MyPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

or to generalize the Uri , its format should be : /{assemblyName};component/{pathToResource}

Just be sure you don't have dot"." in your assembly name as it may result in some uri format exception.

Hope this works.